# AVCaptureSession stopRunning() Mysterious Crash

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Recently I got notified about a crash from firebase and this is the message:

```
[AVCaptureSession stopRunning] stopRunning may not be called between calls to beginConfiguration and commitConfiguration
```

I went through my code and the weirdest part is I never call and there is no mention nowhere of `beginConfiguration()` and `commitConfiguration()`.

In my `CameraManager` class this is the function that triggers the crash, it called on deinit:

```
  func stop() {
    guard isStarted else { return Log.w("CameraManager wasn't started") }
    queue.async {
        self.isStarted = false
        self.isCapturingFrame = false
        self.isCapturingCode = false
        self.session?.stopRunning()
        self.session = nil
        self.device = nil
    }
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    layer.session = nil
}
```

The `queue` is just a serial disptach queue.
No matter what I tried, I couldn't reproduce this crash.
Tried pulling the menu, push notification, phone call, simulate memory warning etc...
Just to clarify, there is not a single place in my code calling `beginConfiguration` and `commitConfiguration`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could imagine that `layer.session = nil` will cause a re-configuration of the capture session (since the connection to the preview layer is removed). And since you are calling `stopRunning()` async, I guess you can run into race conditions where `stopRunning()` gets called right in the middle of the configuration change.

I would suggest you either try to make the cleanup calls synchronous (`queue.sync { ... }`) or move the layer cleanup into the `async` block as well.

Comment: that's interesting!
by calling layer.session = nil an implicit configuration change will be triggered?
worth trying by subclassing, thanks!

Comment: Well yes, since the layer is connected to an output port of the capture session. The setter is conveniently adding/removing that connection for you, but that always requires locking the session for configuration.